# inputValue null , but the value exist

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, element-ui

I am working on a project with Nuxt(Vue) and Element; when I capture the "inputValue" of a "Cascader element" I get null, but if I show the Cascader element porperties by console,  inputValue does have value

Cascader:

```
<el-cascader
ref="cascaderCuentaCosto"
v-model="lineaMaterial.cuentaCosto"
placeholder="Seleccione la cuenta de costo"
:options="listaCuentasCosto"
:show-all-levels="false"
@change="getLabelCuentaCosto">
</el-cascader>
```

function that captures the value

```
getLabelCuentaCosto() {
    console.log("this.$refs['cascaderCuentaCosto']: ", this.$refs['cascaderCuentaCosto'])
    console.log("this.$refs['cascaderCuentaCosto'].inputValue: ", this.$refs['cascaderCuentaCosto'].inputValue
}
```

The first console.log has many properties including inputValue, and his value (in this example) is "second floor". But When get the inputValue in the second console.log, has a null.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Your sample seems to miss some code on the second `console.log()`.

Comment: Correct, and I don't understand why. When used inputValue is null

Comment: the first log logs an object, which shows its newest state when you sees it, the second log being null means at the moment when the function got called, inputValue was not there yet. you can try get it in $nextTick.